# jQuery validation and laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, validation, sentinel

I'm trying to use jQuery validate with laravel and sentinel I need to return false or true but laravel cant do this, instead im trying to do response with text and JSON.
Controller

```
$email = $request->except('_token');
$user_email = Sentinel::findByCredentials($email);
if($user_email!==null)
  return response('This email is already in use!',200)->header('dataType','text');

  return response(collect(["check"=>'ok'])->toJson(),200)->header('dataType','json')
```

Even with response header dataType text ajax accepting this like JSON, but if I write dataType : text in AJAX i can accept only text, and JSON i will see like text and validation still don't working

```
email: {
  required: true,
  email: true,
  name: false,
  remote: {
    url: "/register/check",
    type: "post",
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
    data: {
      username: function () {
        return $("input[name=email]").val();
      }
    },
    // dataType:'text'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

fixed as adding dataFilter, but it's still a bad solution i think

```
email: {
            required: true,
            email: true,
            name: false,
            remote: {
                url: "/register/check",
                type: "post",
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                },
                data: {
                    username: function () {
                        return $("input[name=email]").val();
                    }
                },
                dataFilter: function(data){
                    if(data=='{"check":"ok"}')
                        return JSON.parse(data);
                    return data;
                },
                 dataType: 'text'
            }
        },
```

I'm looking for some answer like 'How can i return false or true in controller on laravel' or 'Accept as reponse multiple dataTypes in AJAX'